# Apply tag to every field in every struct

Tags: go

Is it possible to apply a default struct field tag to every struct / many structs without having to type it out, and also keeps code cleaner.

Eg: when i need omitempty to be applied by default to every struct

```
type SomeStruct struct {
    FieldOne string `json:"field_one,omitempty"`
    FieldTwo string `json:"field_two,omitempty"`
    FieldThree string `json:"field_three,omitempty"`
}
```

Writing middleware for my API to parse all JSON responses, then remove empty fields seems very expensive.

Comment: The go tool doesn't provide any "apply tag to every field in every struct" feature. However you can use the package `go/ast` and its siblings to parse your own source code, then walk the resulting AST and modify the structs by adding the tags you want, and then you can write the modified AST back to the source files.

Comment: What you can do is have a snippet for your IDE. E.g on VSCode you can make snippets with placeholders and case transformation. If done well, here you could just type 2 letters to activate the snippet, then "FieldOne", tab, "string" and your whole line would be what you want it to be. I actually already have had the exact same case (except that using camel case for json) and did that, that helped a lot.

Comment: actually in vscode if you have the go extension installed, you can select the struct fields and then right click and select add struct tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go tool to modify/update field tags in structs. gomodifytags makes it easy to update, add or delete the tags in a struct field. You can easily add new tags, update existing tags (such as appending a new key, i.e: db, xml, etc..) or remove existing tags. It also allows you to add and remove tag options. It supports atom,vscode,vim-go,acme.

> https://github.com/fatih/gomodifytags

Comment: Another Visual Studio Code extension for auto complete the go struct tag when typing. Check it out [link](https://github.com/guyanyijiu/go-struct-tag)